# MPI- Is there any way to find out and display what work is done by each and every core in MPI using Visual Studio?

Tags: mpi

Is there any way to find out and display what work is done by each and every core in MPI using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft MPI is based on MPICH and thus includes the MPICH tracing ability. You can specify the `-trace` option to `mpiexec` and it will result in several trace files. The most important one is the `CLOG2` file, which can then be viewed using the *Jumpshot* tool. It could also produce OTF traces to be analysed by a tool like *Vampir*.

If you happen to use Intel MPI library, the chances are that you have Intel Trace Analyser and Collector (ITAC) bundled with it. It does all the instrumentation and visualisation in a single GUI package.

Visual Studio 2010 (and probably 2012 too) also includes a crude parallel debugger for MPI programs.